# A scam? Has anyone here had dealing with fxhubinvesments or sonicfxtraders - please advise?

Tags: scams

I've lost 1800.00 in a FX exchange investment. They are now promising that after one more final payment I'll get paid out 12 k. This was a bitcoin exchange over 3 weeks.

The profit seems exaggerated and they gave no personal signatures on any emails.  Seems they are running a cloned site. I'm at the point of hiring an investigator to see if I can get anything back.

They won't honor any requests I've made to simply take the commission or fees off the top. I'm sure I'm not alone - any feedback? Fxhubinvesments or sonicfxtraders. The company was dissolved from what I've seen on the registry in England.

Comment: Your money is gone. They're hoping to string you along to get more. An investigator will be a further waste of money. The people you were talking to aren't from the dissolved company, they just used its name. Signatures on emails are meaningless.

Comment: Remember, if someone can consistently turn 1800 into 12k then why would they need your money?

Answer (score 11):

> I ve lost 1800.00 in a fx exchange <s>investment</s>scam

Fixed that for you.

> They are now promising that after one more final payment I'll get paid out 12 k

Yeah... no, they won't.

Consider that $1800 to be tuition for a short course in the School of Hard Knocks, and walk away.  Hopefully you'll be wiser next time you try and make easy money.